# How does this code calculate sum of entered number

Tags: java

I've been learning Java for one week now and I came across this solution for my homework, but I just can't understand how it calculates the sum of numbers.

I've tried to understand it for 1 hour now and I feel so dumb right now.

I pretty much understand that `for` add to `x + 1` every time when the length of the entered number is lower than `x` which is `0`. But I just can't get what the code inside `for` does.

```java
sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(a.charAt(x)));
```

Here is the full code

```java
public class Loader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sum(8313));
    }

    public static Integer sum(Integer number){
        String a = Integer.toString(number);
        Integer sum = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < a.length(); x++) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(a.charAt(x)));
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is a shortcut for `sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(a.charAt(x)));`
The loop goes through all the characters in `a`, transform them into numbers and sum them into the `sum` variable

Comment: Which part of that line confuses you? have you checked the official documentation of the methods used like [Integer.paseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-), [the charAt method of String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) etc. pp?

Comment: I can't understand how this - Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(a.charAt(x))), calculates sum of numbers

Comment: @Celeron It doesn't, that grabs a character from `String a` at position `x`, converts the `char` back to a `String` and then converts it back to an `Integer`.  The calculation comes from `sum += num` which means `sum = sum + num`, where that entire expression is `num`.

Comment: @Celeron Well, you pretty much just repeated your original statement. `Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(a.charAt(x)))` is multiple method calls. So it would be helpfull if you described at which call your confusion starts. Like, do you understand what `a.charAt(x)` does and returns? If yes then do you understand what that result passed into `String.valueOf` will result in etc. pp.

Comment: That‘s some overly complex computation of the checksum / sum of digits of 8313 (15 as result).

Comment: @Nexevis but would it just mean that the sum would be just the same as we entered? `System.out.println(sum(8313))` wouldn't it give us 8313 then? if sum =sum + num (which just takes the next char and return it everytime?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, what you understood was wrong. (Or at least how you put it into words).

The `for` loop is used to loop through a range of numbers. In this case, it loops through `0` to `a.length()`, which is the number of digits in your number (The `number` variable). So in each iteration (or the step of the loop), the value of the `x` increases. It's not `0` all the time.

In each iteration, the `for` loop checks whether the `x` is still lesser than the number of digits in your number. If it reaches the limit, the loop exits.

Before entering the loop, you convert the number to a `String`. So, inside the loop, you first get the character at the index of the value of `x`. Basically, you take the character by character in your number. Then you convert it back to a digit using:

```
Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(a.charAt(x)))
```

Then, it is added to the sum. This is pretty much the same as this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < a.length(); x++) {
  char c = a.charAt(x);
  String s = String.valueOf(c);
  int digit = Integer.parseInt(s);
  sum = sum + digit;
}
```

Your code just does all four steps in one line! When you come up with such cases, try to break down the code like this. That'll help you to understand it better.

Comment: Right now code I provided will give us the sum of this digits 8313 =  15 . But if we will get next char everytime and + to the sum doesn't it mean that it would just do something like 8+1, 3+2, 1+3 and then 3+4 and give us 9547 as the result?

Comment: And thanks for break down! It's a bit easier to grasp what's going on there

Comment: No, it updates the sum value in each iteration. In the first round, it is `8`. Then `8 + 3` which is `11` is assigned to the `sum`. So in the next iteration, the value of the `sum` is `11`. Not `3`. We are doing integer additions. If you find the answer helpful, please accept is.

Comment: OH NOW I see how it works! So the first time it takes just 8, so sum = 8, then a.charAt(x) becomes 1 so it takes 3 and after that sum = 8+3 And after it sum will be = 11 + 1, and then 12 + 3 because it takes next char each time x is less then String's length. Thank you so much! I thought I will never understand it lol

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down the line `sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(a.charAt(x)));`

First of all `sum += 1` is the same as `sum = sum + 1`, so `sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(a.charAt(x)));` is equal to `sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(a.charAt(x)));`

`Integer.parseInt("1")` transforms the String "1" into a number, so `"1" => 1`. Adding a variable of the type String to a number like `sum += "1"` would give an error

`String.valueOf()` on the other hand can transform a number or other datatype into a String, so `1 => "1"`. In this case it is used to transform a Character to the String datatype

`a.charAt(x)` takes the Character from the String `a` at the point `x`
 So if you have `a = "Brentspine"` then `a.charAt(1)` would return `"r"`, since indexing starts at 0

So the line takes the character at position `x` from the String and makes it a string. `Character` is its own class so it has to be transformed into a String. Then this String is transformed into a number and added to the `sum` variable

The `fori loop` repeats itself the length of the String `a` times. For every time it run, the `x` variable gets increased by 1. This way it adds the number at the position `x` of the String `a` to the `sum` variable, which gets returned.
It basically says for the input `"8315"`:
Repeat 4 times, increase `x=0` by 1 every time.
Take the Character of the String at position `a`, make it an `int` and add it to `sum`